# input для числового ввода

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код для числового ввода в input. Работает хорошо, но проблема в том, что буквы вообще не воспринимаются, и перестают работать горячие клавиши, типа `ctrl+a, ctrl+c, ctrl+v`, но хочется, что бы эти функции не терялись.
Вот код:

```
elem = $(this).find($("input.control--suggest--input"));
elem.on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key.length == 1 && e.key.match(/[^0-9+*()\s]/) || e.keyCode == 46) {
        return false;
    }
});
elem1 = $(this).find($("input.control-phone__formatted"));
elem1.on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key.length == 1 && e.key.match(/[^0-9+*()\s]/) || e.keyCode == 46) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Была попытка сделать сделать это с помощью `replace`, дабы клавиши-буквы работали как обычно, а уже после ввода происходило преобразование:

```
if(e.key.match(/[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]/)){
    elem.attr("value",elem.attr("value").replace("^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z]+$",""))
}
```

Но к сожалению ничего не вышло.

Comment: Проверяйте свойство события `e.ctrlKey` на истину, для того, что бы не возвращать `false`, если введена буква с зажатой клавишей ctrl

Comment: @vihtor Боже, это гениально!!!!!! Работает, спасибо огромное!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю так (чистый JS):

```js
var a = document.querySelector('input');

a.addEventListener('input', function() {
  var regExp = new RegExp('[^' + this.getAttribute('pattern') + ']', "g");
  this.value = this.value.replace(regExp, '');
});
```

```html
<input type='text' pattern="\d.">
```

Comment: можно ввести например `11.11.11..11`

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин можно добавить `.replace(/^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1');` и проблема решена :)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит  использовать стандартный инпут для ввода цифр

Comment: Стандартный инпут для ввода цифр позволяет ввести символ `e` в верхнем и нижнем регистре. Это с одной стороны хорошо(если сайт создан для сложных математических расчетов) с другой стороны - если в БД попробовать положить такое, или попытаться совершать математические операции над этим (как в `js` так и на сервере) - всё будет валиться. Поэтому ваш ответ не подходит, использование `input type="number"` не решает всех проблем.

Comment: А еще можно не пихать бездумно всё в базу данных и не забывать про серверную валидацию. А то кто-нибудь отключит яваскрипт и завалит ваш сервер.

Comment: @Klimenkomud По моему мнению ответ дельный. Дело в том, что нормальный человек туда не будет вводить eE, но даже если введёт, это просто формат записи числа такой, результатом всё-равно является число, которое можно спарсить или на стороне клиента или на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <input type="text" name="input" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
```